# PHP PDO_ODBC desde Linux Debian a Access97

Tags: php, pdo, ms-access, odbc

Necesito acceder a unas bases de datos (en Access97) que genera un aparato medidor que nos han instalado. Este aparato genera un fichero Access97 (N_01_XXXXXX.mdb) por dia, con las lecturas que realiza.

He instalado el driver PDO_ODBC en mi Linux, pero al realizar la conexión desde PHP me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found'
PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER={Mi...')
```

El codigo que utilizo para la conexión es el siguiente:

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/doc/datamdb/N_01_240920.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
   die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

En la configuración del PHP, me aparece el PDO_ODBC como instalado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

.. sin embargo, los ficheros `odbc.ini` y `odbcinst.ini` de la carpeta `/etc` esan vacios.

¿que información debo incluir en estos ficheros?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientación ...

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro. No encuentra el archivo, revisa el path que le estás pasando a la variable `$dbName`

Comment: El archivo lo encuentra, si no mostraría el msg anterior "Could not find database file". El error lo da al cargar fichero lib del controlador ...

Comment: [Este artículo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095532/how-to-add-support-for-ms-access-mdb-to-php7-pdo-in-ubuntu-18-04) seguramente te va a resultar útil para saber porqué no funciona y cómo corregir el problema.